# sequence generator mapping for Grails POJO domain class

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, sequence, pojo

I have POJO domain class in Grails/PostgreSql app and I'm trying to map postgres sequence generatorg for its ID.

In POJO:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "flight_id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

In Postgres:

```
-- Sequence: flight_id

-- DROP SEQUENCE flight_id;

CREATE SEQUENCE flight_id
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1n 
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE flight_id
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I try running grails generate-all for that domain I get:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: flight_id
```

Everything else seems to working ok, except this. I'm trying to use Postres native generator so I have the option of running CRUD operations against the DB that is independent of the Grails app.

Any hints would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two problems:

1. usage of GenerationType.AUTO (persistence provider chooses strategy freely) when GenerationType.SEQUENCE seems to be preferred and
2. false assumption that `flight_id` in `generator = "flight_id"` refers directly to the name of database sequence, when it actually refers to: (following directly from documentation):

   > The name of the primary key generator to use as specified in the
   >   SequenceGenerator or TableGenerator annotation

What should be done is changing strategy to [GenerationType.SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#SEQUENCE) and defining [SequenceGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) that is consistent with database sequence and does have same value for *[name](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#name%28%29)* attribute as is value of *[generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html#generator%28%29)* attribute in GeneratedValue.